# Asp.net get submit method not working when url is mapped

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms, get, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a asp.net mvc form and i want to submit it to same page via get method, it's used for search purpose.

The url is mapped with route key value id.

```
@using (@Html.BeginForm("Contact", "Home",FormMethod.Get))
{
    @Html.TextBox("id", null,
            new
            {
                type = "time"
            }
                );
    <input type="submit" />
}
```

When the form is generated the **action** attribute is containing the key value like **/Home/Contact/myname**.

Here **myname** is value of id present in url.

When form is submitted value key value for id is getting appended to URL like

http://localhost:57247/Home/Contact/myname?id=11%3A11

The action method is reading myname value instead of **11%3A11**.

Action Method:

```
public ActionResult Contact(string id)
{
   ViewBag.Message = id;
   return View();
}
```

It's working fine with post method.

How to fix this?

Comment: Why are you using `get` for a form submission? Also, please show your controller action method.

Comment: Added action method in question, get method is used to show the parameter values in url like done by search engines.

Comment: Do you use default routing configuration? Html.BeginForm passes id to controller as routeValue (myname), and textbox adds id to querystring, so they conflict with each other. Try to rename id to something different, or better add 2 parameters to contoller method - Contact(string id, string time) and change textbox to use 'time' as name - you will see what will happen.

Comment: @Artem, Yes, this uses default routing. Infact the application is from the 2013 default template without any modification, i have used it to show this issue. 

I will make the suggested changes and will update.

Comment: I don't understand where `myname` comes from? If you have the form and   action method as written above and you use the default routing, i.e. `{controller}/{action}/{id}`,  the generated url will have the form `http://localhost:63348/Home/Contact?id=02%3A01` which will bind nicely with your action method.

Comment: @Christian, Right, that's what i expected also. myname is value of paramter id.It's same as  http://localhost:57247/Home/Contact?id=myname since id is url mapped it's shown like http://localhost:57247/Home/Contact/myname. This issue is happening when url has already a value for id and full route and taken as action of form instead of controller and action.You can try yourself and see.

Comment: @Satyajit I have tried myself with the exact same code as above and it works as intended. If possible, post all your code to a Github repo or gist.

Comment: @Christian, Can you check when url is like http://localhost:57247/Home/Contact/myname and not like http://localhost:57247/Home/Contact?id=myname. This is the case when it's having issue. You can change myname to any other value also :)

Comment: @Satyajit Typing localhost:57247/Home/Contact/myname in the browser address field and pressing enter will invoke the `Contact` action method with 'myname' bound to `id` argument. But when does this scenario occur? When I press Submit the generated url is localhost:57247/Home/Contact?id=02%3A01. See my repo here: https://github.com/chribben/RouteIssue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace  `@Html.BeginForm("Contact", "Home",FormMethod.Get)`
with `@Html.BeginForm()`

By default forms are sent to same url they are rendered on and default method is get.
`@Html.BeginForm()` by default produces a METHOD="POST"

As for your parameter you might want to name it differently.
Default Mvc route is configured like this

```
  routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Depending on mvc version it can be in global.asax or App_Start\routeconfig.cs

So your "MyName" in url perfectly matches default id parameter and it has higher priority than query string parameters.
If you name your parameter differently (not id).
Change it to "q" for example in action and in view.
Your URLs will change to  /Home/Contact?q=myname and everything should start working as expected.

Now you say that you want a solution with url mapping.
So you have to figure out for yourself what url scheme you want.

If you have a form and want it to post to /home/contact/myname?id=notyourname, than you have a conflict which to solve you will have to somehow change binding priorities in mvc.
Now you can inspect querystring on your own in your action and figure out new id passed without binding. After that you can return `RedirectToAction("Contact", new{id = figuredId})` and the url in browser will be what you want it to be.

You can change the query parameter name and have your action recieve 2 parameters

```
public ActionResult Contact(string id, string q){
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhitespace(q)){
      return RedirectToAction("Contact",new{id=q});
    }
 }
```

To send request to /Home/Contact you should use `@Html.BeginForm("Contact","Home",new{id=null}, FormMethod.Get)`

Comment: Same issue with @Html.BeginForm(). 'By default forms are sent to same url they are rendered on and default method is ge't.   This is not correct i think as i am not able to see the params in url and as per https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd505244(v=vs.118).aspx, Writes an opening <form> tag to the response. The form uses the POST method, and the request is processed by the action method for the view i.e. default submit method is post.

Comment: With change of parameter form will work fine but i am looking for solution with url mapping i.e. to use the routing.

Comment: Thanks, this is a good work around but it would involve a server round trip. Can you suggest how to submit directly to '/home/contact' instead of '/home/contact/myname'? Which i feel is the root issue here.

Comment: Also, correct the action method, here all paths does not return value.

Comment: Appended solution  with submit to /home/contact